# C++ Switch statement executes after break

Tags: c++, switch-statement, break

I am trying to write a C++ program to score the paper-rock-scissor game.
Each of two users types in either P, R, or S.
The program then announces the winner as well as the basis for determining the winner: (I have to use switch statements and can't use any if, if-else, else if statements)

The problem I am having is i am getting 2 outputs because it is executing after breaks. for example Scissors cuts Paper.
Player 2 WINS!
Scissors cuts Paper.
Player 1 WINS!

Here is my code, thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char pl1;
char pl2;

cout << "Enter [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors" << endl;
cout << "Player 1: ";
cin>>pl1;

cout << "Enter [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors" << endl;
cout << "Player 2: ";
cin>>pl2;

switch (pl1)
{
    case 'R':
    case 'r':
    {
        switch(pl2)
            case 'P':
            case 'p':
        {
            cout << "Paper beats Rock." << endl;
            cout << "Player 2 WINS!" << endl;
            break;
        }
            case 'S':
            case 's':
        {
            cout << "Rock smashes Scissors." << endl;
            cout << "Player 1 WINS!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
}
switch (pl1)
{
    case 'P':
    case 'p':
    {
        switch(pl2)
            case 'R':
            case 'r':
        {
            cout << "Paper beats Rock." << endl;
            cout << "Player 1 WINS!" << endl;
            break;
        }
            case 'S':
            case 's':
        {
            cout << "Scissors cuts Paper." << endl;
            cout << "Player 2 WINS!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
}
switch (pl1)
{
    case 'S':
    case 's':
    {
        switch(pl2)
            case 'R':
            case 'r':
        {
            cout << "Rock smashes Scissors." << endl;
            cout << "Player 2 WINS!" << endl;
            break;
        }
            case 'P':
            case 'p':
        {
            cout << "Scissors cuts Paper." << endl;
            cout << "Player 1 WINS!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
}
switch (pl1)
{
    case 'R':
    case 'r':
    case 'P':
    case 'p':
    case 'S':
    case 's':
    {
        switch(pl2 == pl1)
        {
            case true:
            {
                cout<<"Nobody wins"<<endl;
                break;
            }

        }
        break;
    }
    break;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's an incorrect assertion: `break` is `break` to a switch statement. It's not possible for code within that same switch to be executed afterwards .. and a little better indenting consistency would be dandy.

Comment: Is it just a syntax error? It looks like you've forgotten to add `{` (and the respective closing `}`) after the inner `switch(pl2)` lines. Also, you should be able to remove the second and third `switch (pl1)` lines - when you're `switch`ing on the same thing twice in a row, they should be able to be combined.

Comment: What is `switch(pl2 == pl1)`? That's the job of an if statement.

Comment: Thank you very much! adding the { } fixed it! As for removing the second and third switches could you dumb it down for me a bit more please, sorry i am just starting to program.

Comment: I was not allowed to use any if, if-else or else-if statements. It was the only way I could think of

Comment: Consider using `?:`, such as `cout << ((p2 == p1) ? "Nobody wins" : "")`.  Also consider using `switch(std::toupper(pl1))` rather than `switch(pl1)` to reduce number of distinct cases you need to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that you are missing `{`...`}` around the (intended) bodies of some of your switch statements, causing all the cases except the first to become part of the enclosing switch statement.  As an example, your first coupound switch:

```
switch (pl1)
{
    case 'R':
    case 'r':
    {
        switch(pl2)
            case 'P':
            case 'p':
        {
            cout << "Paper beats Rock." << endl;
            cout << "Player 2 WINS!" << endl;
            break;
        }
            case 'S':
            case 's':
        {
            cout << "Rock smashes Scissors." << endl;
            cout << "Player 1 WINS!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
}
```

is actually (with added braces and fixed indentation):

```
switch (pl1)
{
    case 'R':
    case 'r':
    {
        switch(pl2) {
            case 'P':
            case 'p':
            {
                cout << "Paper beats Rock." << endl;
                cout << "Player 2 WINS!" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    case 'S':
    case 's':
    {
        cout << "Rock smashes Scissors." << endl;
        cout << "Player 1 WINS!" << endl;
        break;
    }
    break;
    }
    break;
}
```

so with input `'r'` and `'p'`, it prints the first message, then falls through into the `'s'` case and prints the second message...

What is most suprising is that you don't see any compiler warnings about this, even with -Wall -Wextra -- this definitely seems like something the compiler should warn about.

Comment: Thank you for your help!, I'm using the latest Xcode and it didn't flag anything.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all code tha looks like

```
}
switch (pl1)
{
```

Except the last one.

Add default clauses.

Add return statements after you print victory information instead of breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of your code that works as intended.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char pl1;
    char pl2;

    cout << "Enter [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors" << endl;
    cout << "Player 1: ";
    cin >> pl1;

    cout << "Enter [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors" << endl;
    cout << "Player 2: ";
    cin >> pl2;

    switch (pl1)
    {
        case 'R':
        case 'r':
        {
            switch (pl2)
            {
                case 'P':
                case 'p':
                {
                    cout << "Paper beats Rock." << endl;
                    cout << "Player 2 WINS!" << endl;
                    break;
                }

                case 'S':
                case 's':
                {
                    cout << "Rock smashes Scissors." << endl;
                    cout << "Player 1 WINS!" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case 'P':
        case 'p':
        {
            switch (pl2)
            {
                case 'R':
                case 'r':
                {
                    cout << "Paper beats Rock." << endl;
                    cout << "Player 1 WINS!" << endl;
                    break;
                }

                case 'S':
                case 's':
                {
                    cout << "Scissors cuts Paper." << endl;
                    cout << "Player 2 WINS!" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case 'S':
        case 's':
        {
            switch (pl2)
            {
                case 'R':
                case 'r':
                {
                    cout << "Rock smashes Scissors." << endl;
                    cout << "Player 2 WINS!" << endl;
                    break;
                }

                case 'P':
                case 'p':
                {
                    cout << "Scissors cuts Paper." << endl;
                    cout << "Player 1 WINS!" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    switch (pl2 == pl1)
    {
        case true:
            cout << "Nobody wins" << endl;
            break;
    }
}
```

The main mistake you made was about forgetting to add a scope for the inner `switch(pl2)` blocks, which lead to the double-firings.